# Is it possible to have a parameter as the first node of a route?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'd like to have the following type of route in ASP.NET MVC.

- `{a}/{b}` -> SiteController.Search(a, b) (where a and b are arbitrary strings)

While still having a HomeController

- `home/index` -> HomeController.Index()

Is this possible?  Is it possible if the home controllers routes are hardcoded?
ie:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Home",                   // Route name
            "Home/{action}",          // URL with parameters
            new { action = "Index" }  // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible without removing the default route because the routing engine cannot disambiguate between those two urls:

```
foo/bar
home/index
```

Assuming you want the first to match `{a}/{b}` and the second `{controller}/{action}`. Even if you hardcode the route as in your example `home/index` will always match the first route which is `{a}/{b}`.

Also if `a` and `b` can be arbitrary strings it would be better if they were passed as query string parameters.